# fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/home/vagrant/ProjectsTest/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied

Tags: laravel, git, homestead

I have trouble with Laravel Homestead and Git, it seems that Git does not have permission to clone project (in this case from [gitlab.com](https://www.gitlab.com)).

I am using a fresh new installation of Laravel Homestead, latest `release` branch. Also shared folder `ProjectsTest` is set to have `777` permissions but it still does not work.

https://superuser.com/questions/677550/git-cannot-clone-repository-into-cifs-mounted-directory

All I could find is this question where error is almost the same as in my case. This question seems unsolved...

> vagrant@homestead:~/ProjectsTest$ git clone git@gitlab.com:owner/agency-website.git
>   Cloning into 'agency-website'...
>   remote: Enumerating objects: 339, done.
>   fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/home/vagrant/ProjectsTest/agency-website/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
>   fatal: index-pack failed
>   remote: Counting objects: 100% (339/339), done.

Everything should work fine, I cannot see why git does not have permissions.

Comment: Just because you have `777` on `ProjectsTest` doesn't mean you have `777` on subdirectories

Comment: @MattMessersmith what is your suggestion? I can clone into ~ on Homestead, I did it as a test. It seems that this is related somehow to `ProjectTest` shared folder because I can do `git clone` as root or as user from my local machine

Comment: Having the same problem. The only way around I've found is to not use git clone from homestead but directly on the folder where you have all your sites connected to homestead. After this the problem I've encountered is that composer update haves some issues, not sure why.

Comment: @JorgePeña I could not solve the issue so I tried to use NFS. I managed to set up everything successfully and now git and everything else is working fine, just like before issue encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your Homestead vagrant box to v8.0.1 (`vagrant box update`), this version was released 4 days ago. I had similar problem to yours except with `git add` and `git commit` commands, and updating the vagrant box solved it.

https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1240

Additionally make sure you have Vagrant (2.2.5) and VirtualBox (6.0.10) on newest version.

Comment: I already tried to update but now I am using NFS and everything works fine